# Time Need to validate for timepicker in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, event-handling, timepicker

I need to validate a selected time from the time picker. So if the selected time is not valid then I need to display a toast message.

Which event will trigger if time will select from the time picker?

And I don't want to bind the time if the selected time is not valid based on my condition.

XAML Code:

```
<controls:DatePickerCustom FontSize="14" HeightRequest="35" Date="{Binding CustomDate,Mode=TwoWay}" MaximumDate="{Binding MaximumDate}" FontFamily="Segoe UI" Format="D" IsEnabled="{Binding IsDatePickerEnable}">
                                    <DatePicker.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger TargetType="DatePicker" Binding="{Binding IsCustomSelected}" Value="true">
                                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{DynamicResource HeadingTextColor}" />
                                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{DynamicResource HeadingTextColor}" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </DatePicker.Triggers>
                                </controls:DatePickerCustom>
```

Answer (score 0):

Handle this in your "setter" for property `CustomDate`.

In a setter, the new value is `value`. If `value` isn't valid, Show the toast message. Return from setter, without changing the internal field that holds the value, and without calling `OnPropertyChanged`.

If you need more information, please show the code that declares property `CustomDate`.

It that property is currently an "auto-property", convert it to a "full-property" - this will have a "backing field", and gives you a place to do the test, and reject the change.

Answer (score 0):

You could listen the `PropertyChanged` event of `TimePicker`,then match the `Time` property.

For example:

```
<TimePicker PropertyChanged="TimePicker_PropertyChanged"></TimePicker>


private void TimePicker_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TimePicker timePicker = sender as TimePicker;
        if (e.PropertyName.Equals("Time") )
        {
            var time = timePicker.Time;
            if (time.Minutes == 10) // your condition
            {

            }
            else
            {
                DisplayAlert("Warning", "This is a validate time", "Cancel");
            }
        }
    }
```